# multiple networks in keepalived configuration

Tags: linux-networking, keepalived, vrrp

I have two router(lxc containers) seated in the distribution layer of my network and I want to implement HA for them. The routers have 114 network interfaces and I want that they share a virtual ip address, I have seen that a way to acomplish this is with keepalived, but in all the configurations I've seen with multiples ip adresess, all the ips belong to the same network range and this of course is not what I want. In a test environment I used a simple config, show it below, and it work pretty fine, but I dont know if this is correct and what effects it will have when I configure 114 interfaces. I want to know if there is a best way of configuring diferent VIPs of diferent network ranges.

```
vrrp_instance Example_Inst {

# State = Master or Backup
state MASTER

# Interface ID for VRRP to run on
interface eth0

# VRRP Router ID
virtual_router_id 20

# Highest Priority Wins
priority 150

# VRRP Advert Intaval 1 Second
advert_int 1

# Basic Inter Router VRRP Authentication
authentication {
auth_type PASS
auth_pass 123456789
}

# VRRP Virtual IP Address Config
virtual_ipaddress {
192.168.100.2/24 dev eth0

192.168.1.1/24 dev eth1

192.168.2.1/24 dev eth2
}
}
```

Thank you for your time.